Passing arguments while building ROS 2 python pkg using colcon build
Is there anything that can help with the customized building of the Python pkg in ROS 2?
I found it is possible to pass arguments with pkg type ament_cmake. But I couldn't find any documents for python pkg. I suppose something similar can be helpful.
My situation.
I have created one package, but for some cases, users need to use just part of the pkg, so I want to build some nodes, dynamically modify some parts of the code, and remove the unnecessary ones. There can be six different building possibilities, and it uses some shared files. So I prefer not to create separate pkgs.
I am looking for something like this (afaik --build-args tag doesn't exist),
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select <pkg_name> --build-args <build_args>

Any help is appreciated!
